# VBA: Extract values from multiple Workbooks/sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to take the different values from column C of a workbook and compile the unique ones, either on the same sheet, new sheet or in a new workbook.

For example Col. C may contain 50 rows of the value 'Excel2' and 150 values of 'Word2', I would just need the Excel2 and Word2 to be shown somewhere, just once. Perhaps in a new sheet/workbook stating the column C header.

This is my macro so far, maybe altering the '`lrng.formula`' part would help:

```
Sub Calculationallsheetsv2()
'Calculation all sheets, even when there is only headers

Dim xrng As Range, lrw As Long, lrng As Range, i As Long
Dim LstCo As Long, ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then

            LstCo = .Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column
            For i = 1 To LstCo
                With .Columns(i)
                    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
                End With
            Next

            lrw = .Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
            If lrw = 1 Then lrw = 2
            Set lrng = .Range("A" & lrw + 2)

            With .Range("A2:A" & lrw)
                lrng.Formula = "=COUNTA(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")/ROWS(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")"
            End With

            Set xrng = .Range(lrng, .Cells(lrng.Row, LstCo))

            lrng.AutoFill xrng, Type:=xlFillDefault
            xrng.Style = "Percent"
        End If
    End With
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.CalculateFull

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the Dictionary Object in VBA, it can behave like a Set with no duplicates, so it might save some work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Excel's built-in `AdvancedFilter` feature to do this. For example, this grabs the unique values from column `C` on `Sheet1` and puts them in column `C` on `Sheet3`:

```
Sheet1.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , Sheet3.Range("C1"), True
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, where would I add that into my code? Im pretty newb so im having trouble running it.